# JasperReports: PDF generation with image from database

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I want generate PDF File with an image. The image name from database and physically the image is present inside local drive or remote server. I want to pass image name to the PDF.

Currently I am doing this by put an image element inside the *iReport* IDE designer and pass the server path or local drive path to that image.

It works fine. But I need some other type for dynamic images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the image can be reached by the app with a URL you can add a paramter named `IMAGE_SRC`, and specify in the iReport designer

```
image expression: new java.net.URL($P{IMAGE_SRC})
expression class: java.net.URL
```

for the image. Then at runtime you will fill the report after setting the parameter `IMAGE_SRC` with the value readed from the database

Comment: @soljava The editors really are [Alex K and George Stocker](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/11671231/revisions). If this answer is useful to solve your problem you should upvote and accept it. If it isn't, you could try to explain what's wrong and we'll find another way

Comment: Its working fine. But , I have used directly the `$P{IMAGE_SRC}` without use of 'java.net.URL' and works fine.